# Suma de horas entre 2 campos datetime Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en mi bbdd que tiene 3 campos:

`usuario` `hora_inicio` `hora_final`

En la aplicación, el usuario se logea y al hacer click en un botón, guarda primero en el campo `hora_inicio` la hora actual. Cuando el usuario vuelve a hacer click, se guarda la hora actual pero esta vez en el campo `hora_final`

Necesito crear un informe donde salga las horas totales de cada usuario en un mes. Por ejemplo, ahora mismo en la tabla tengo lo siguiente:

```
usuario    hora_inicio           hora_final
========   ===================   ===================
usuario1   2019-05-03 08:00:00   2019-05-03 16:00:00
usuario2   2019-05-03 08:00:00   2019-05-03 16:00:00
usuario1   2019-05-06 08:00:00   2019-05-06 16:00:00
usuario2   2019-05-06 08:00:00   2019-05-06 16:00:00
```

El informe debe salir de la siguiente manera:

```
usuario      dias_trabajados     total_horas/mes
========     ===============     ===============
usuario1           2                   16
usuario2           2                   16
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me sume todas las horas de cada usuario y las convierta en dias_trabajados?

Estoy haciendo la siguiente función, pero solo sé para un día en concreto.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIME(TIMEDIFF(hora_final, hora_inicio)),'%H:%i') as horas 
  FROM horario 
  WHERE pk_horario = 1;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece entender que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT usuario,MONTH(hora_inicio) mes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(hora_inicio)) dias_trabajados,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hora_final,hora_inicio)))
  ),'%H:%i')
  total_horas_mensuales
  FROM jornadas GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Que, para tu dataset, proporciona el siguiente resultado:

> ```
> usuario   mes dias  total_horas_mensuales
> usuario1  5   2   16:00
> usuario2  5   2   16:00
> ```

Adjunto dataset en formato SQL para facilitar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE jornadas(
  usuario varchar(15),
  hora_inicio datetime,
  hora_final datetime
  );
INSERT INTO jornadas (usuario, hora_inicio, hora_final) VALUES
  ('usuario1','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario1','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00');
```

Únicamente te había faltado agrupar por día y mes.

Comment: Exactamente lo que buscaba, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Hola, como podría hacer para que en vez de números enteros en el `total_horas_mensuales` , me saliera con minutos tambien?

Comment: Sin inconveniente, modifico la respuesta para que incluya minutos

Answer (score 0):

Pues mira la diferencia entre dos horas, sumas todas y divides el resultado por las horas del turno.

```
$f1 = new DateTime('2019-05-03 08:00:00'); //inicio
$f2 = new DateTime('2019-05-03 16:00:00');//fin

$diferencia = $f1->diff($f2);
$intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

$resultado = $intervalo->format('%H');//%Y años %m meses %d days %H horas %i minutos 
%s segundos

$horario = 8; //las horas por turno
$resultado = $resultado / $horario;
```

Asi a groso modo creo que te deberia funcionar, prueba.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Otra aproximación para sacar la diferencia de horas es usar [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php). La ventaja es que admite directamente horas como unidad.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE jornadas(
  usuario varchar(15),
  hora_inicio datetime,
  hora_final datetime
  );
INSERT INTO jornadas (usuario, hora_inicio, hora_final) VALUES
  ('usuario1','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario1','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario1','2019-05-06 09:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-06 11:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT usuario,MONTH(hora_inicio) mes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(hora_inicio)) dias_trabajados,
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,hora_inicio,hora_final))
  total_horas_mensuales
  FROM jornadas GROUP BY 1,2;

| usuario  | mes | dias_trabajados | total_horas_mensuales |
| -------- | --- | --------------- | --------------------- |
| usuario1 | 5   | 2               | 23                    |
| usuario2 | 5   | 2               | 21                    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

EDITADO para añadir como calcular horas y minutos
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE jornadas(
  usuario varchar(15),
  hora_inicio datetime,
  hora_final datetime
  );
INSERT INTO jornadas (usuario, hora_inicio, hora_final) VALUES
  ('usuario1','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-03 08:00:00','2019-05-03 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario1','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-06 08:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00'),
  ('usuario1','2019-05-06 09:00:00','2019-05-06 16:20:00'),
  ('usuario2','2019-05-06 11:00:00','2019-05-06 16:00:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT usuario,MONTH(hora_inicio) mes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(hora_inicio)) dias_trabajados,
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,hora_inicio,hora_final))
                    total_min_mensuales,                      SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,hora_inicio,hora_final)) total_horas_mensuales,
    (SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,hora_inicio,hora_final))-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,hora_inicio,hora_final))*60)) min                                                                           


  FROM jornadas GROUP BY 1,2;

| usuario  | mes | dias_trabajados | total_min_mensuales | total_horas_mensuales | min |
| -------- | --- | --------------- | ------------------- | --------------------- | --- |
| usuario1 | 5   | 2               | 1400                | 23                    | 20  |
| usuario2 | 5   | 2               | 1260                | 21                    | 0   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Muchas gracias! También me puede servir

Comment: Hola, como podría hacer para que en vez de números enteros en el `total_horas_mensuales` , me saliera con minutos tambien?

Comment: De modo rápido puedes poner MINUTE en lugar de HOUR en TIMESTAMPDIFF, luego en php puedes sacar fácilmente las horas a partir de los minutos, o bien hacerlo en la query, aunque si son muchos datos puede ralentizar. Te añado el ejemplo a la respuesta